# jstree icons missing when deploying jhipster application

Tags: css, bower, jhipster, jstree

I need to add jstree (version 3.3.4) as a bower dependency to a jhipster project (jhipster version 2.20.0 - not the current version!).

Using the dev profile or when starting the application from my IDE, everything works fine.
But when I deploy using the production profile, the .css files of the project get merged into one big file called `assets/styles/something.vendor.css` when packing the .war file, while images seem to get copied to `assets/images/`.
The web browser ends up asking for `assets/styles/32px.png`, which results in 404.
Instead when using dev profile, styles and images are both loaded from `bower_components/jstree/dist/themes/default/`

But jstree seems to expects it's icons next to it's css file by referncing them directly (e.g. `background: url(32px.png)`).

What I tried:

I managed to overwrite some of the rules by adding for example

```
.jstree-default .jstree-file {
    background: url(../images/32px.png) -100px -68px no-repeat  !important
}
```

to the projects main css file (`src/main/webapp/assets/styles/main.css`) and manually adding the images to `assets/images`.

But jstree seems to have most icons packed into one .png-file  - and then shifting/cutting it according to which icon is needed using css rules. This makes it hard to get it to look right.

Using my approach the icons can be loaded - but they are not cut as they should for some (unknown) reason:

[image: result]

So I tried to overwrite attributes like `repeat: no-repeat`
or    `background-color: transparent` as well (from my understanding they should be present already as they are part of jstree's css and not overwritten by my rules), but the rules seem too complex and I can not get it to look right and I'm hoping for a better solution.

How can I resolve this issue without having to 'rewrite'/overwrite most of jstree's css rules?

Comment: Understand JHipster prod build process and exclude jstree from it either by configuration or by moving jstree in another folder manually (not using bower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by excluding jstree from the gulp build process (thanks for the hint @Gaël Marziou) by:

1. making sure jstree is listed in `bower.json` under "devDependencies", not under "dependencies"
2. adding `'main/webapp/bower_components/jstree/dist/jstree.js',` to jstree (like it was added by bower initially)
3. editing index.html so that

   - jstree's style.css is included **after** `<!-- endbuild -->` in the head section
   - jstree's javascript file is includes **after** the `<!-- endbower -->` and `<!-- endbuild -->` comments

This way jstree is not packed into `vendor.css` so that both style and images are loaded from the original location (`bower_components/jstree/dist/`.

Comment: Hello, i'm just having the same problem. The jstree css is looking in the vendor instead of style.css

in the first step, i have a dependence called "ng-js-tree": "~0.0.7". I should bring her to devDependencies?

in the second step, i dont unsderstand what i have to do with this path: 'main/webapp/bower_components/jstree/dist/jstree.js'

in the third step, i dont have a end bower, just a <!-- build:js app/app.js  -->